# how to change column name in every ajax request through loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to switch column name each time in ajax call? Consider the db having columns as 1,2,3,4.....30 and on each ajax request I want the response of radio button to be saved in same column as its question no. i.e. question 1 response will be stored in column 1 and so on. How to increment column index as question no. using a single query.

Need to solve the controller query only.

Working on codeigniter.

Getting question id in quest field.

var quest = $('#mquest').val();

Here is the ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
                     url: '<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/save_answer',
                     type: "post",
                     dataType: "html",
                     data:'hint='+hint+''+quest+'&<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>=<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>',
                     success: function(data) {
                }
            });
```

Here is the controller:

function save_answer()
{

```
         $data['$quest']=$this->input->post('hint');
         $this->base_model->save_update($data,$this->db->dbprefix('answers'));
 }
```

Here is the model:

```
 function save_update($data, $table, $email = '')
{       

    // $this->db->insert('questions',$data);
    if ($this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix($table), $data))
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
```

}

Need to switch different columns i.e. question 1 get stored in column named 1 and so on.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] detailing what you have done so far and why it is not working for you. Also provide an example of the required output.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you ajax posted data will be,
with your radio button value create a format like this:

- for question 1:

radio button value as `value="value-1"`

Controller:

```
function somename(){
    //Get posted value
    $question=$this->input->post('question');

    //Explode it
    $column=explode("-",$question,2);

    //This will split the 1 from the question-1
    $column_id=$column[1];
    $data=array(
         'column_name'.$column_id=>$column[0]
    );
    $this->db->insert(Table_name,$data);
 }
```